# Video closes but doesn't open again

Tags: jquery, html

Below is the code in which when the button is clicked the video opens and then after closing it, if we re-try to open the video. Only the popup opens but the video won't be visible.

Please help

jQuery:

```
$("[data-media]").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var videoUrl = $this.attr("data-media");
    var popup = $this.attr("href");
    var $popupIframe = $(popup).find("iframe");

    $popupIframe.attr("src", videoUrl);



    var left = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    var left = left/2 - 340;

    var top = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
    var top = top/2 - 180

    document.getElementById("vid").style.top = top + "px";
    document.getElementById("vid").style.left = left + "px"; 

    $this.closest(".page").addClass("show-popup");
    $('.page iframe').attr("src", '');
});

$(".popup").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    $(".page").removeClass("show-popup");
});

$(".popup > iframe").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="page"> <!-- class "page" is required for video to work-->
        <div class="popup" id="media-popup"> <!-- video embedded -->
            <iframe id="vid" src="http://testvideo.com" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div><!-- popup -->
</div>
```

Comment: The video source attribute is cleared here: `$('.page iframe').attr("src", '');`. Just remove that ?

Comment: but then the video won't stop playing even after closed @LouysPatriceBessette, is there anything you can suggest.

Comment: Okay... If I'm right, `$(".popup").on("click", function(e) {` closes the popup. So what if you place `$('.page iframe').attr("src", '');` in that script instead of the one that loads it?

Comment: That doesn't help either, I tried to place it as you suggested. The video stops but when again opened the video won't appear.